# Cannot start Java SE app with -javaagent option on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, newrelic, javaagents

I'm trying to get a Java Application to work with New Relic on Elastic Beanstalk. It's a Java app with no New-Relic-supported framework.

The errors reported in the logs are:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument

Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /var/app/current/newrelic.jar
```

The command I use to start is:

```
java -javaagent:/var/app/current/newrelic.jar -jar target/bs.jar
```

The layout of my source bundle is as follows:

```
├── Procfile
├── newrelic.jar
├── newrelic.yml
└── target
    └── bs.jar
```

It works fine on my local machine, and the app also works fine on Elastic Beanstalk if I remove the `-javaagent:...` option.

What am I missing?

Thanks,

Val

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem in my build. The newrelic.jar file was corrupted. AFAIK, as of now, there is no problem with this setup.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: how does your build affect the newrelic.jar file? It should not be built by you, so I am wondering what has happened to it.

Comment: Nothing wrong with newrelic.jar :) it was a copy error in my script.

Answer (score 0):

Just verify that the file `/var/app/current/newrelic.jar` is there, and then that the OS user you are using is allowed to read it. The errormessage is explicitly stating that it could not access the file via the path specified.

Comment: it is there, with the same read permissions as all the other files. Is there anything else I can try ?